# All-In-One shell extension code sample download - CSShellExtContextMenuHandler

Tags: c#, .net, shell-extensions

Can anyone provide somewhere to download the now removed `CSShellExtContextMenuHandler` app which demonstrated how to build a shell extension in .NET 4?

It used to be included in the All-In-One code framework:
http://1code.codeplex.com/

But it was removed by Microsoft:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codefx/archive/2011/01/04/is-it-officially-supported-to-write-windows-shell-extension-using-net-4-today.aspx

But for personal use it could have been quite handy.

Answer (score 0):

Goto https://github.com/blak3r/openop/tree/master/CSShellExtContextMenuHandler and look at FileContextMenuExt.cs.